# Flutter: how do I pass Gradle params when building an APK?

Tags: android, flutter

When building a regular Android app with Gradle, I can add params as such:

```
./gradlew assembleRelease -Pusername=foo -Ppassword=bar
```

With Flutter, this is what I'm supposed to call in order to assemble an APK:

```
flutter build apk
```

How do I pass the params to Gradle in this case?

P.S. I'm trying to use Jenkins credentials in a pipeline configuration. I do not want to expose my password, so avoiding using the arguments and putting it directly into the project is not an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass variables via the environment, I use this method with Jenkins. The job can be configured to pass the credentials via environment variables.

In your `build.gradle` (where needed):

```
username = System.getenv('SECRET_USERNAME')
password = System.getenv('SECRET_PASSWORD')
```

Please notice that `System.getenv(...)` returns `null` if the variable is not defined.

In your development environment you should export the variables:

```sh
$ export SECRET_USERNAME="my secret username"
$ export SECRET_PASSWORD="my super secret password"
```

Please, I do not know which IDE are you using, but both IntelliJ and AndroidStudio do support declaring environment variables.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Problem is: this way the credentials are exposed to my development environment. I don't want to export them, as they would be visible to everyone with the access to the build runner machine in this case

Comment: Well, the variables are visible only in the shell in which you declared them and sub-shells of that one. I'm not advising to add the credentials to your `.bashrc`.

Comment: Where in Android Studio can I put `export REDIRECT_SCHEME="my redirect scheme"`?

Answer (score 0):

You can set project properties through environment variables like `ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_foo=bar`, so that you don't have to modify the gradle scripts, for example:

```
export ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_username=foo 
export ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_password=bar
flutter build apk
```

Docs: [Project properties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:project_properties)